# How can I export a lot of XML file with different names from Access VBA?

Tags: xml, ms-access, vba, visual-web-developer

I'm exporting a XML file from access with this code. I have to export a lot of xml files into the same carpet and they don't have to be replaced. But, in the code I don't know how to write that on DataTarget.

```
Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportTable, DataSource:="Customers", _
                      DataTarget:="Customer Orders.xml", _
                      AdditionalData:=objOrderInfo
End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to better explain your issue. What is your current code doing and how is the behaviour different from what you expect? Does the code work at all? Does it give you an error? Please be specific.

Comment: My current code is exporting the table Customers to a XML file with the name "Customers Orders", and yes, it works. But, what I really need is the users can specify the name of the XML that I'm going to create. For example, I have a form with a text command where they can write "T3362" and then clic on a button and save a XML file with that name. If they want another name, write again and clic on a button. 

So, How can I do that? What do I have to say in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to retrieve the file name that the user entered and then pass it to `Application.ExportXML`, something like this:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdPerformExport_Click()
    Dim fname As String
    ' Text Box control is named "txtExportFileName"
    If IsNull(Me.txtExportFileName.Value) Then
        MsgBox "You did not enter a file name."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    fname = txtExportFileName.Value
    Application.ExportXML _
        ObjectType:=acExportTable, _
        DataSource:="Customers", _
        DataTarget:=fname & IIf(Right(fname, 4) = ".xml", "", ".xml"), _
        AdditionalData:=objOrderInfo
End Sub
```

If you want additional error checking (e.g., file name only contains valid characters, drive/path exists, etc.) you will need to add that, too.

Comment: that's great! BUT "Data Target says The file name and path for the exported data. If this argument is omitted, data is not exported". So, I need to write both. The real problem is how can write the name "fname" AND PATH like "C:/XML_FILE". Please help me.